# How does _get_timezone work?

Tags: c++, c, time

I'm trying to correct a timestamp class that's acting up really weird.
What it has to do is to get the current time upon construction or the time passed as a string.

I only want to work with UTC as these dates are not really displayed anywhere but the difference between one timestamp and another is.

In any case, I call the `strptime(timestamp, m_format.c_str(), &time);` to get the tm time from a string. This string is UTC time so if I want to call `mktime` to get time as time_t I have to modify it with the current timezone so I do this `time.tm_hour-=tz/3600` where `tz` is retrieved by calling `_get_timezone`. The problem is that this function seems to return 28800 which is the default value but if I call it later in the code it will give me -7200 which is the right value.

Do I have to do anything to get this value initialized? We have a big codebase and I don't know everything that happens in between.

Furthermore if anyone has a link to a similar class I'd really appreciate it as I'd probably notice my mistake there.

Thank you.

Comment: Are you changing the timezone of your system in two different calls?

Comment: Side note: Your "time.tm_hour-=tz/3600" may be a secondary problem as the timezone difference is half-hour multiples in various parts of the world.  Recommend time.tm_sec -= tz;

Comment: "acting up really weird"

Answer (score 1):

I would define my own function time_offset as follows

```
#include <time.h>
double time_offset()
{
    time_t now = time(NULL);

    struct tm *gm = gmtime(&now);
    time_t gmt = mktime(gm);

    struct tm *loc = localtime(&now);
    time_t local = mktime(loc);

    return difftime(local, gmt);
}
```

This was taken from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15911278/get-timezone-alternative)
Hope this helps

Answer (score 1):

_get_timezone() returns the Redmond default of 28800 (Pacific Standard Time) prior to something else calling _tzset(). _tzset() will be called implicitly by many assorted time-based functions (localtime/mkttime do not appear to call this, however).

I too experienced a problem with it not being initialized, or with it being initialized, then flipping back to 28800, then initializing again. I've decided to avoid it altogether.

Here's the mechanism I used to obtain the information on Windows. This does not suffer apparent initialization race in _get_timezone:

```
TIME_ZONE_INFORMATION tz;
DWORD rc = ::GetTimeZoneInformation(&tz);
offset_minutes = tz.Bias + (TIME_ZONE_ID_DAYLIGHT != rc ?  tz.StandardBias : tz.DaylightBias);
offset_seconds = offset_minutes * 60;
```