# _get_timezone alternative?

Tags: c++

I am converting a C++ project that compiles only on a windows machine, since it uses microsoft C++ libraries. Is there any alternative for the function `_get_timezone`, compilable on an Ubuntu 12.10 machine?

[_get_timezone](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/38wx0s70(v=vs.80).aspx) documentation on MSDN

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think I'd just compute it myself, using the standard functions:

```
#include <time.h>

namespace time_util { 
double get_gmt_offset() { 
    time_t now = time(NULL);

    struct tm *gm = gmtime(&now);
    time_t gmt = mktime(gm);

    struct tm *loc = localtime(&now);
    time_t local = mktime(loc);

    return difftime(local, gmt);
}
}
```

I haven't tested them side by side to be sure, but this returns about what I'd expect _get_timezone to return (e.g., for me, it returns -25200, which works out to UTC-7 hours).

The one place you might need/want to "fiddle" with things a bit is with dealing with `tm_isdst` -- I didn't look closely enough at `_get_timezone` to see whether it takes that into account or not.

Comment: thanks! working perfectly!
I imagine I will have to fiddle with daylight savings time though.

Answer (score 1):

The Linux alternative to `_get_timezone` is not a function, but simply the `timezone` variable, defined in `time.h`:

```
extern long timezone;
```